# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I am busy studying for a Linear Algebra test and came across this question in Section 4.4 of Elementary Linear Algebra (Application Version) $11^{th}$ edition.

This is not part of my work that needs to be covered in the test, but I thought it would be interesting to see how this can be proven. Can anyone please show me how this can be done? :)

Comment: Can you verify all the axioms? I believe that's what they're asking.

Comment: Write down th edefinition of $\mathbb R^\infty$. This leads you through most of the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tne vectors $e_n $ where  $$e_n (k) =\begin{cases} 1 \mbox{ if } n=k \\ 0 \mbox{ if } n\neq k\end{cases} $$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Right answer.  Proving infinite dimension does not require proving that they span.  They may not (depending on the definition not given by the OP) span $\mathbb R^\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$$A = \{(1,0,0,...), (0,1,0,0,...),...\}$$ span $\Bbb R^\infty$ and it is very easy to check they are all linearly independent.

Added: $A$ is an infinite set, so $dim(\Bbb R^\infty)$ is infinite by definition of $dim()$.

Comment: How can it be checked that they are all linearly independent? :).

Comment: Try to write one of the vectors as a nontrivial linear combination of the others...